# rename AWS glue output file as .json/.parquet

Tags: python, aws-glue, file-format

I have below code which writes data into AWS s3 location using Glue job, but at the end it is saving in part file, but my requirement is to save filename as filename.json or filename.parquet

```
s3_loc  = "s3a://s3_location/path"

##this is the default part of the glue script
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dbname", table_name = "tableName", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("user id", "string", "user id", "string"), ("e-mail", "string", "e-mail", "string"), ("e-mail 2", "string", "e-mail 2", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

timestampedDf = applymapping1.toDF().withColumn("export_timestamp", current_timestamp())

df = timestampedDf.withColumn("client", lit("122")).withColumn("partition_date", current_date()).coalesce(1)

dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "dyf")

print("---------> Let's go <---------")
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dyf, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": s3_loc , "partitionKeys": ["client","partition_date"]}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")

print("---------> Let's finish <---------")
job.commit()
```

anyone can help to save data in correct fileformat with extenstion as .json or .parquet ?

I have below code which writes data into AWS s3 location using Glue job, but at the end it is saving in part file, but my requirement is to save filename as filename.json or filename.parquet

```
s3_loc  = "s3a://s3_location/path"

##this is the default part of the glue script
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dbname", table_name = "tableName", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("user id", "string", "user id", "string"), ("e-mail", "string", "e-mail", "string"), ("e-mail 2", "string", "e-mail 2", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

timestampedDf = applymapping1.toDF().withColumn("export_timestamp", current_timestamp())

df = timestampedDf.withColumn("client", lit("122")).withColumn("partition_date", current_date()).coalesce(1)

dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "dyf")

print("---------> Let's go <---------")
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dyf, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": s3_loc , "partitionKeys": ["client","partition_date"]}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")

print("---------> Let's finish <---------")
job.commit()
```

anyone can help to save data in correct fileformat with extenstion as .json or .parquet ?

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible. Glue is using Spark under the hood which assigns those names to your files.

The only thing you can do is to rename the files after writing.

Answer (score 0):

So as direct saving file with extension like .json / .parquet is not possible in Glue job hence I tried renaming file name and below is working code - I hope this is useful for who need help in this topic and saves a lot of time for developer who needs to do this in future.

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext, DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,year,month,dayofmonth,current_date,to_date,lit,current_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import boto3

## @params: [TempDir, JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

s3_loc  = "s3a://bucket-name/prefixFolder1/prefixFolder2/"

job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "databaseName", table_name = "tableName", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("user id", "string", "user id", "string"), ("e-mail", "string", "e-mail", "string"), ("e-mail 2", "string", "e-mail 2", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

timestampedDf = applymapping1.toDF().withColumn("export_timestamp", current_timestamp())

df = timestampedDf.withColumn("client", lit("122")).withColumn("partition_date", current_date()).repartition(1)

dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "dyf")

datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dyf, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": s3_loc, "partitionKeys": ["client","partition_date"]}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()

client = boto3.client('s3')
BUCKET_NAME='bucket-name'
PREFIX='prefixFolder1/prefixFolder2'

response=client.list_objects(
    Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
    Prefix=PREFIX)
    
file_name=response['Contents'][0]['Key']
copy_source={'Bucket': BUCKET_NAME,'Key':file_name}
print("file_name :" +file_name)

client.copy_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, CopySource=copy_source, Key=file_name+".json")
client.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=file_name)
```